# PHP regular expressions - Replacing one backreference

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Is there a way in `preg_replace()` or `preg_replace_callback()` to replace only one backreference? For instance I have this regular expression: `/(\.popup)([\s\.{])/` and this string `.popup .popup-option`. The backreferences that will be generated are as follows: `$0 = .popup\s`, `$1 = .popup`, `$2 = \s`. I want to replace only the `$1` by another string. How do I manage to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` like this:

```
$s = '.popup .popup-option'; // original string

echo preg_replace_callback('/(\.popup)([\s\.{])/', function ($m) {
    return 'foo' . $m[2]; }, $s);
//=> foo .popup-option
```

In the callback we are returning some replacement string `foo` concatenated with `$m[2]` thus getting only `$m[1]` replaced.

---

Do note that using lookahead you can do the same in `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.popup(?=[\s\.{])/', 'foo', $s);
//=> foo .popup-option
```

Comment: The only scenario I was missing was that it can be only `.popup` which doesn't work with this regex because I'm specifically saying that it has to be followed by either space, dot or {. Either way, I slightly changed your answer into `/\.popup((?=[\s\.{])|\z)/`